# Copy postal code to point shapefile

Tags: attribute-table, attribute-joins

I have a layer with postal codes represented by polygons and another layer with points.

I want to copy the postal code attribute to the points layer based on what postal code the point is in.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can spatially join your point layer to the polygon layer, imparting all attributes of the polygons onto the points